React Router Dom v6 Dynamic Route
Migrating from react-router-dom v5 to v6, there is some problem to show page element when using v6 Route function
previously on v5 I used these code:
App.js
import routes from "../../routes/routes";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
.....

export default function App () {
 return (
        <HashRouter>
          <Switch>
            routes.map((route, idx) => {
                      return (
                        route.component && (
                          <Route
                            key={idx}
                            path={route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            name={route.name}
                            render={(props) =>
                              (<route.component {...props} />)
                            }
                          />
                        )
                      );
                    })}
          </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
  );
}

routes.js
import React from 'react';
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('../pages/home/Home'));
const Home2 = React.lazy(() => import('../pages/home/Home2'));

const Routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/home2',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Home2',
    component: Home2
  }
]

export default Routes;

on v5 it can run correctly but it fails to run on v6
I already changed Switch into Routes
and used element to render, here is some change I made
                  <Routes>
                    {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                      return (
                        route.component && (
                          <Route
                            key={idx}
                            path={`/app` + route.path}
                            exact={route.exact}
                            name={route.name}
                            element={
                              <route.component {...props} />
                            }
                          />
                        )
                      );
                    })}
                  </Routes>

I also tried to change element with component but it still doesn't work, is there something I missed that might can show correct page?
edit-1:
I also tried to use element={ React.createElement(route.component, props) } 
but it also didn't work
edit-2:
fixed the issue by removing exact on Route

react-router-dom v6 syntax should be:
 <Route path='/' element={<route.component/>}/>

did  should be there? I used  instead of  and it show no error, if it required, should I placed it inside/outside HashRouter?

I use "import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';"

@TheKNVB https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router it has the same 'level' with BrowserRouter

Other than props being not being declared when passed to route.component the code you have runs without issue. See this running sandbox demo. What exact specific issue are you needing help with here? Please [edit] to clarify what the problem is and what you need specific help with. I invite you to take the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Since I can't reproduce the issue you describe and you haven't responded to refute or clarify anything I'm voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo".

@DrewReese sorry for late response, I found the issue on my code, react route v6 is not used exact component on Route anymore, after removing exact it can run correctly

Odd... React components generally ignore extraneous props. Maybe you are using Typescript? But then that would throw a different and more obvious error and message. Glad you have it working though. Cheers.

The correct syntax for react-router-dom v6 is
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path={'/login'} element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>


Can you add the link to the documentation please?
